# Understanding how text() works

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

Based on experimentation, it seems that when I set an element's text using an undefined value, the element's text does not change from the previous value. I wanted to confirm this is true.

For example, I've written the following function:

```
$deleteButton.click(function(e) {
        $('h1').text($(this).parent().data("component").name);
        $(this).parent().data("component", null)
        $('h2').text($(this).parent().data("component").name);
}
```

This code sets an element's data 'component' to null and then tries to access a value that is normally contained in the data "component". Since the element's data "component" has been set to null however, I expected the text for 'h2' (which first shows "Test h2") to change to "". However it still shows "Test h2" after the $deleteButton.click() has been executed. Does this mean that if the value is null for the text it will just keep the original text contained in the element?

Thanks.

Comment: See here https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L310-L320

Comment: If the value passed in is undefined, does it just return the value as though you had called .text()?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery silently ends most methods if something isn't found, be it an element or a value. Apparently it simply doesn't complete the operation if `$(this).parent().data("component").name` doesn't exist.

Update: The [**link**](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L310-L320) elclanrs posted seems to confirm.